# SQL Oracle to select a column that displays the highest value in a result set

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an existing query that loads a specific dataset. Please see sample table for illustration

```
 Select I.Invoice_ID, I.Invoice_Date, CI.Unit_Rate
 FROM Invoice I, ChargeInvoice CI


Invoice_ID   Invoice_Date  Unit_Rate
A1           05/08/2018    100
A2           04/08/2018    200
A3           03/08/2018    300
B6           04/06/2018    150
C5           04/15/2018    2000
```

What I need to  add a calculated column which displays the MAX or highest value of one field in the result set, that can be named as MAX_UNIT_RATE.

The expected result set is something like this

```
  Invoice_ID   Invoice_Date    Unit_Rate   Max_Unit_Rate
    A1           05/08/2018    100         2000
    A2           04/08/2018    200         2000
    A3           03/08/2018    300         2000
    B6           04/06/2018    150         2000
    C5           04/15/2018    2000        2000
```

I tried this, but It is not getting the desired result

```
select IV.INVOICE_ID, IV.INVOICE_DATE , ICV.UNIT_RATE, MAX(ICV.UNIT_RATE) AS MAX_UNIT_RATE
FROM INVOICE_V IV,  
    INVOICE_CHARGE_V ICV
 GROUP BY IV.INVOICE_ID,  IV.INVOICE_DATE, ICV.UNIT_RATE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be writing your query with correct `join` conditions.  The solution to your problem are window functions:

```
SELECT I.Invoice_ID, I.Invoice_Date, CI.Unit_Rate,
       MAX(CI.Unit_Rate) OVER () as MAX_Unit_Rate
FROM Invoice I JOIN
     ChargeInvoice CI
     ON I.Invoice_Id = CI.Invoice_ID -- this is a guess
```

Comment: When I apply it in my actual query with many more tables (not joined) it is not working.. could it be because of the unjoined tables?

Comment: Are there alternative ways like Sub Select Query?

Comment: Window/analytic functions are the right way to solve the problem.  There are inferior solutions that use other methods.